# How to create a poll app in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have to create a poll app using Ionic Framework. My knowledge on this framework is a bit limited, and I'd be very gratefull if someone could help me a bit.

All the 'trivial' things are already done. My problem is creating the poll itself dynamically. I know the main structure of that poll. I even get that information from server side app. But I can't figure out how to place that poll on the app, or even how to store the answers given.

The poll structure is as follows:

```
categories: [
    {
        category1_data,
        questions: [
            {
                question_data,
                answers [{answer1},{answer2},...]
            }, {question2}, ...
        ]
    }, {category2}, {category3}, ...
]
```

I guess this can be done by reloading some kind of custom component, and storing given answers on a page's variable, but still don't have any clue about how to show that info. 
PD: That component should show up an entire 'category' each time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your question is a bit vague and lacks details on what exactly you are having problem with.
Anyways I will try to give some suggestions.

1. After getting data from the server inside a component iterate using *ngFor to display the poll json inside your template.
2. Take user input for the poll and save it locally(SQLite storage /localstorage) or send directly data to the server and just refresh the component to show the updated poll result.

Fell free to message me if any more clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `ng-for`. `Ng-for` allows you to to iterate over json data and display the data. The example below repeats over json array called items.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your case you can iterate over your category json array, displaying each question and answers.

I hope this helps, if you need a more detailed example please feel free to message me.

Comment: [Extra Info](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#lists) on `ng-for`, when used in ionic.